# Digital Ocean One-Click-Install-Image Django/Ngnix with HTTPS

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, digital-ocean

I'm fairly new to django and nginx, and I started using DigitalOcean's one-click-image install Django 1.6 environment which uses nginx and gunicorn. The default specifications and details can be found here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image.

Recently, I have been trying to figure out how to secure the admin page for deployment with SSL/HTTPS to prevent login capture. And I realize there is information on this on stackoverflow already. However, it seems like most information has base settings for nginx that differ from Digital Oceans. So, I'm a little thrown for what I should keep, edit and delete.  At this moment I'm satisfied with proxy over two instances in nginx: flat pages being under HTTP and the admin under HTTPS as this is simply going to be a launch page. How would you secure the entire site behind https? What would be the necessary modifications to the following nginx and Django settings?

Nginx Settings

```
upstream app_server {
server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

client_max_body_size 4G;
server_name _;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# Your Django project's media files - amend as required
location /media  {
    alias /home/django/django_project/media;
}

# your Django project's static files - amend as required
location /static {
    alias /home/django/django_project/static; 
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
}
```

Django Settings

```
"""Production settings and globals."""

from __future__ import absolute_import

from os import environ

from .base import *

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CRSF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# Honor the 'X-Fowarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

########## HOST CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#allowed-hosts-required-in-  production
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    '{{website url}}',
]
########## END HOST CONFIGURATION
########## EMAIL CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host
EMAIL_HOST = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com')

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host-password
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', '')

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host-user
EMAIL_HOST_USER = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER', 'your_email@example.com')

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-port
EMAIL_PORT = environ.get('EMAIL_PORT', 587)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-subject-prefix
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[%s] ' % SITE_NAME

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-use-tls
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#server-email
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
########## END EMAIL CONFIGURATION

########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
DATABASES = {}
########## END DATABASE CONFIGURATION


########## CACHE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches
CACHES = {}
########## END CACHE CONFIGURATION


########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
SECRET_KEY = get_secret("SECRET_KEY")
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.